# One liner for matrix and vector square sum

Tags: python, list, sum

Given a matrix an a vector, with the same number of columns

```
matrix = [[1, 1, 0, 0],
          [1, 0, 1, 0],
          [0, 0, 1, 1]]
vector = [1, 2, 3, 2]
```

Step 1: sum

```
matrix_b = [[2, 3, 3, 2],
            [2, 2, 4, 2],
            [1, 2, 4, 3]]
```

Step 2: squares

```
matrix_c = [[4, 9,  9, 4],
            [4, 4, 16, 4],
            [1, 4, 16, 9]]
```

Step 3: sum of squares

```
matrix_d = [[26], [28], [30]]
```

I'm currently doing this:

```
scores_sq = []
pp = len(vector)

for item in matrix:
    aux_sum = 0
    for p in range(pp):
        aux_sum += (vector[p] + item[p])**2
    scores_sq.append(aux_sum)
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can write `matrix_b` using a nested comprehension:

```
matrix_b = [[r + v for r, v in zip(row, vector)] for row in matrix]
```

Adding `matrix_c` is trivial:

```
matrix_c = [[(r + v)**2 for r, v in zip(row, vector)] for row in matrix]
```

Summing the rows is easy too in this formulation:

```
matrix_d = [sum((r + v)**2 for r, v in zip(row, vector)) for row in matrix]
```

If you want to keep the nested lists, put the sum in a list too:

```
matrix_d = [[sum((r + v)**2 for r, v in zip(row, vector))] for row in matrix]
```

Comment: Thanks!, I was struggling with the nested comprehension, until now I only used single comprehesions.

Comment: @Errorx404.  Don't forget to select the answer by clicking on the check mark next to it